# Slot Props for Accordion Component

Tags: typescript, frontend, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm trying to create a timeline component that is essentially a glorified accordion with different modes. `single`: only one item can be displayed at once. `multiple`: multiple items can be shown at once.

1. How do I make a component that acts like this:

```
<Timeline mode="single">
  <TimelineItem id="01-23-2004">
    <button slot="title">Title</button>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
  </TimelineItem>

  <TimelineItem id="01-24-2004">
    <button slot="title">Title</button>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
  </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

1. While trying to work on this, I ran into another problem. Is there a way to pass a prop to every element inside of a slot? That is `<slot {mode}>` would be able to pass `{mode}` to every element let's say if `<slot {mode}>` is replaced with multiple `<TimelineItems>`.

This is my svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/78c254fa119243f999e4934d9f712802?version=4.2.0).

This is my current code (I've tried many different combinations of slot props):

`timeline.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { setContext } from "svelte";
  import { writable, type Writable } from "svelte/store";

  export let open = "single";
  switch (open) {
    case "single":
      // reactive context
      let activeId: Writable<string> = writable<string>("");
      setContext<Writable<string>>("activeId", activeId);
      break;

    case "multiple":
      break;

    default:
      throw new Error("Invalid timeline mode");
  }
</script>

<div class="flex overflow-y-auto flex-col p-4">
  <slot {open} />
</div>
```

`timeline-item.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { getContext } from "svelte";
  import type { Writable } from "svelte/store";

  export let id: string; // date
  let activeId = getContext<Writable<string>>("activeId");
  $: active = $activeId === id;

  export let open: string;

  export let handleClick = () => {
    if (active) {
      activeId.set("");
      return;
    }

    activeId.set(id);
  };
</script>

<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <slot name="title" {handleClick} />
  </div>

  {open}

  {#if active}
    <div class="pl-10">
      <slot name="content" />
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

`+page.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import TimelineItem from "$lib/timeline/timeline-item.svelte";
  import Timeline from "$lib/timeline/timeline.svelte";
</script>

<Timeline open="single">
  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2006" let:open> <-- ERROR
    <svelte:fragment slot="title" let:handleClick>
      <button slot="title" on:click={handleClick}>Title</button>
    </svelte:fragment>
    <p slot="content">Content</p>
  </TimelineItem>

  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2004" let:open> <-- ERROR
    <svelte:fragment slot="title" let:handleClick>
      <button slot="title" on:click={handleClick}>Title</button>
    </svelte:fragment>
    <p slot="content">Content</p>
  </TimelineItem>

  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2005" let:open> <-- ERROR
    <svelte:fragment slot="title" let:handleClick>
      <button slot="title" on:click={handleClick}>Title</button>
    </svelte:fragment>
    <p slot="content">Content</p>
  </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

`Error`:

```
Property 'open' is missing in type '{ id: string; }' but required in type '{ id: string; open: string; handleClick?: (() => void) | undefined; }'. 7:4:1 ts2741
Property 'default' does not exist on type '{ title: { handleClick: () => void; }; content: {}; }'. 7:40:1 ts2339
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but I don't know if it is an ideal solution. This is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f49533f18dd44090acd1964d65fabe51?version=4.2.0). I feel like it is a hacky way of solving my problem:

`timeline.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { setContext } from "svelte";
  import { writable } from "svelte/store";

  export let open: string;
  setContext("open", open);

  switch (open) {
    case "single": {
      setContext("activeId", writable()); // reactive context
      break;
    }
    case "multiple": {
      break;
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error("Invalid timeline mode");
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="flex overflow-y-auto flex-col p-4">
  <slot />
</div>
```

`timeline-item.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { getContext } from "svelte";
  import type { Writable } from "svelte/store";

  export let id: string; // date
  let open = getContext("open");
  let activeId: Writable<string> = getContext("activeId");
  $: active = $activeId === id;
  let handleClick: () => void;

  switch (open) {
    case "single": {
      active = false;
      handleClick = () => {
        if (active) {
          activeId.set("");
          return;
        }
        activeId.set(id);
      };
      break;
    }
    case "multiple": {
      active = false;
      handleClick = () => {
        active = !active;
      };
      break;
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Cannot handle open type: {open}`);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="flex">
  <button on:click={handleClick}>
    <slot name="title" />
  </button>

  {#if active}
    <div class="pl-10">
      <slot name="content" />
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

`+page.svelte`:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import TimelineItem from "$lib/timeline/timeline-item.svelte";
  import Timeline from "$lib/timeline/timeline.svelte";
</script>

<Timeline open="single">
  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2006">
    <div slot="title">Title</div>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
  </TimelineItem>

  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2005">
    <div slot="title">Title</div>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
  </TimelineItem>

  <TimelineItem id="01-20-2004">
    <div slot="title">Title</div>
    <div slot="content">Content</div>
  </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

The iffy part I'm hesitant about is in `timeline-item.svelte` where I define both `activeId` and `active` even though I don't need to when I set the `open` mode to `"multiple"`.